# opengl32.dll is not needed by VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse, freeglut

The code as follows:

```
   #include <GL/glut.h>

GLfloat light_diffuse[] = {1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0};  /* Red diffuse light. */
GLfloat light_position[] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0};  /* Infinite light location. */
GLfloat n[6][3] = {  /* Normals for the 6 faces of a cube. */
  {-1.0, 0.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 1.0, 0.0}, {1.0, 0.0, 0.0},
  {0.0, -1.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 0.0, 1.0}, {0.0, 0.0, -1.0} };
GLint faces[6][4] = {  /* Vertex indices for the 6 faces of a cube. */
  {0, 1, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 6, 7}, {7, 6, 5, 4},
  {4, 5, 1, 0}, {5, 6, 2, 1}, {7, 4, 0, 3} };
GLfloat v[8][3];  /* Will be filled in with X,Y,Z vertexes. */

void
drawBox(void)
{
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glNormal3fv(&n[i][0]);
    glVertex3fv(&v[faces[i][0]][0]);
    glVertex3fv(&v[faces[i][1]][0]);
    glVertex3fv(&v[faces[i][2]][0]);
    glVertex3fv(&v[faces[i][3]][0]);
    glEnd();
  }
}

void
display(void)
{
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  drawBox();
  glutSwapBuffers();
}

void
init(void)
{
  /* Setup cube vertex data. */
  v[0][0] = v[1][0] = v[2][0] = v[3][0] = -1;
  v[4][0] = v[5][0] = v[6][0] = v[7][0] = 1;
  v[0][1] = v[1][1] = v[4][1] = v[5][1] = -1;
  v[2][1] = v[3][1] = v[6][1] = v[7][1] = 1;
  v[0][2] = v[3][2] = v[4][2] = v[7][2] = 1;
  v[1][2] = v[2][2] = v[5][2] = v[6][2] = -1;

  /* Enable a single OpenGL light. */
  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, light_diffuse);
  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);
  glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
  glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

  /* Use depth buffering for hidden surface elimination. */
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

  /* Setup the view of the cube. */
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  gluPerspective( /* field of view in degree */ 40.0,
    /* aspect ratio */ 1.0,
    /* Z near */ 1.0, /* Z far */ 10.0);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  gluLookAt(0.0, 0.0, 5.0,  /* eye is at (0,0,5) */
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0,      /* center is at (0,0,0) */
    0.0, 1.0, 0.);      /* up is in positive Y direction */

  /* Adjust cube position to be asthetic angle. */
  glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -1.0);
  glRotatef(60, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  glRotatef(-20, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
  glutCreateWindow("red 3D lighted cube");
  glutDisplayFunc(display);
  init();
  glutMainLoop();
  return 0;             /* ANSI C requires main to return int. */
}
```

I download the freeglut and `copy all files in include/GL folder to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include\gl` and also `copy all files in lib folder to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib`. and `copy freeglut.dll to C:\windows\system32`

Then in VS 2010, I add freeglut.lib to VS 2010 (additional dependent library). It works well.

I plan to use Eclipse to build the project and configure Eclipse according to this [setting eclipse in window 7](http://elleestcrimi.me/2010/10/06/setting-glut-eclipse-windows/)

However, if I just add the link library `freeglut`, it does not work. I have to add `freeglut` `opengl32` and `glu32` together to make the program run.

The problem is why in VS 2010, I only need `freeglut` but in eclipse I need to explicitly add the three libraries?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is probably auto-linking. But gcc does not support auto-linking.

Check [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/Compiler/Linker/Libraries/Static_and_Dynamic_Libraries)